# Connecting to Geth Node using Web3 WebSocket Provider resets every 2 hours

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, web3-providers

I have a Node JS application which connects to a Geth Node using the [Web3WsProvider](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/tree/1.x/packages/web3-providers-ws#usage) which under the hood uses [W3CWebSocket](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/a2cd3065167668a9685db0d5f9c4083e8a1839f0/docs/W3CWebSocket.md#w3cwebsocket).

The app starts and connects to the node and is set mostly to make read only calls to the node. This works fine, except that at exactly every 2 hours, the WebSocket connection to the node resets and the app then needs to reconnect. While I have configured the `Web3WsProvider` to automatically reconnect, any connection drop is undesirable as during this moment there are possible events that my application needs to capture and could potentially miss.

I am unable to find anything in the source code of the `Web3WsProvider` or `W3CWebSocket` libraries that I am using that would cause this connection reset to occur every 2 hours so it would appear it is Geth that is causing this connection reset.

Is there something that I can do to avoid Geth resetting the WebSocket connection every 2 hours like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this is a specific issue with Amazon Managed Blockchain (AMB) where the Geth node was running. This appears to be the same 2-hour hard limit “Connection duration for WebSocket API” of AWS API Gateway beneath. Note that I've confirmed this with an AWS Support Engineer.

So a simple workaround, when faced with a similar condition to this (either using AMB or another provider), is to re-establish a new connection just before, in `setTimeout()` and handle dupe events, or `ws.onclose()` with potentially missed events.

Alternatively, just switch providers to one that does not have the 2-hour hard limit such as QuikNode or even by running your own private Geth node.